# Binary values of cryptographic keys

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography

I'm using Python 3.7 and the NaCl cryptography library. I'm trying to print the binary values of the public and private keys. So far I can only print the hex values with this code:

```
import nacl.utils
from nacl.public import PrivateKey, Box

skbob = PrivateKey.generate()
print( bytes(skbob).hex() )
```

Can someone tell me how to print the keys binary value?

Comment: The binary value will be illegible in ASCII, do you mean print the actual 1's and 0's? Remove the .hex().

Comment: Nice! I read your post from about 11 month ago. I tried it without hex, but then i get something like b'\xd4\x90Wa\....... But i want the 1's and 0's.

Comment: updated with an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can print the actual `1's` and `0's` of the secret key using this code:

```
import nacl.utils
from nacl.public import PrivateKey, Box

def access_bit(data, num):
    base = int(num // 8)
    shift = int(num % 8)
    return (data[base] & (1<<shift)) >> shift

skbob = PrivateKey.generate()

print( bytes(skbob).hex())

print([access_bit(bytes(skbob),i) for i in range(len(bytes(skbob))*8)])
```

You will see an output like this:

```
b32965d39933fc447a5c3bcdb00b73ef5de0b9cd88aba35a1743e38d88c8bec1
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

And as you will see, this is `256-bits` of entropy, just as expected.

FWIW, I did the same when I was learning about cryptography, there is something really nice in seeing the raw data, and getting your hands dirty with the low level stuff.

Best,
Woodstock

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great answer, but now I'm pretty confused. AFAIK my code generates keys for Curve25519. Those private keys have a defined structure: Shouldn't the second bit of the list (254 bit) always be a 1? And why is it possible to generate odd values for private keys? ( I think the last bit should always be 0 ).

Comment: Excellent question, you're talking about "clamping" of the key... I love that you are exploring this so deeply. I did the EXACT same and asked the SAME question :D - see the answer here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/75940/key-clamping-in-curve25519-not-evident-in-generated-keys-binary-representation ... in a nutshell, clamping is done on the fly, not on the generated key...

Comment: So now I read about it and this is what I understood: The private key gets generates as a 255 bit random number and is stored this way. When the public key is generated, the privates key gets clamped. This means, the privates key gets the shape it need (last 3 bits are set zero, second bit is set to 1). Example: I generate 1000...1111 and after clamping i get 1100...1000

Comment: After thinking about it, the Example should be: 0000...1111 --clamping-> 1000...1000